# undefined method `build_part' for 1:Integer when creating a belongs_to association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app where the User `has_one` Account and then the Account `belongs_to` User. I want other pieces of data to inherit from the Account (such as Products or Parts). But I can't figure out how to create a new Part and assign the new Part to the current user's Account on create.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to build the new Part like this:

```
@account = current_user.account.id
@part = @account.build_part(part_params)
```

That results in this error:

```
undefined method `build_part' for 1:Integer when creating a belongs_to association in rails
```

And, I tried this as well:

```
@account = current_user.account.id
@part = @account.build.parts(part_params)
```

But that gives me this error:

```
undefined method `build' for 1:Integer
```

What is the correct way to do this in Rails? (Currently running the beta version of Rails 6.)

Here is the relevant code:

Models...

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :parts
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :part_category
  belongs_to :part_unit
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Clearance::User
  has_one :account
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the account record in `@account` and not just its id, in order to build parts related to an account. 
The problem lies in this section of the code:

```
@account = current_user.account.id
@part = @account.build_part(part_params)
```

Here, we initialize `@account` with the current user's account id, instead of the account record. This results in `@account` holding an integer value(the account's id). And integers do not have any method called `build_part` defined for their class by default, which results in an error! 
Simply changing `@account = current_user.account.id` to `@account = current_user.account` should work.
You can read more about building associations [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/build_association)

Comment: Thanks! Removing 'id' from 'account.id' worked along with `@part = @account.parts.build(part_params)`. That makes sense, but why doesn't `@part = @account.build_part(part_params)` work? That gave me this error: `undefined method build_part for #<Account:0x00007fe990ed8308> Did you mean? build_user`. Why is that?

Comment: `@part = @account.build_part(part_params)` this gives an error because the `has_many` association does not introduce `build_association` method to the declarative model. As described here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many , `has_many` introduces this method: `collection.build(attributes = {}, ...)` instead, which is why `@account.parts.build` would work. 
However, `belongs_to` introduces `build_association`: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to

Answer (score 1):

```
@account = current_user.account.id
```

is an integer so of course it results in an error. Just remove the `id` part.